# Finding a catapult for the Off You Go Achievement

Tags: achievements, trine-2, trine-2-goblin-menace

Trine 2 Goblin Menace has added an achievement called "Off You Go", to get which one must catapult a goblin trapped in a Monster Prison. Where can one find a catapult to get this achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a catapult in the first level of The Goblin Menace, just after you go outside the tavern and do the 3 platforms puzzle.

Use the lever to operate it.

[image: It's the thing in the left!]